# Swift - display live video from external camera

Tags: ios, swift, http, live-streaming

I'm trying to display a live view that I can get from an external camera in my app. I'm not sure how to do that exactly.

I can make a post request that will return binary data (MotionJPEG) for the live view that is transferred by Content-Type: multipart/x-mixed-replace. ([here](https://developers.theta360.com/en/docs/v2/api_reference/commands/camera._get_live_preview.html) is the reference)

But I'm unsure about how to pipe this data to a view to display it, and how I can used the build in AV classes since it seems that the default way to do video over http is with a get request. I've been using Alamofire so far for networking and I don't see an easy way to use it with for a stream of data.

Any idea / experience welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I too am trying to find out how to do this in Swift 3.

The lua based Corona Labs SDK can access the live camera feed and apply it to an object with one line of code ( https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/ShapeObject/fill.html#camera-source-fill ).  You can subscribe to Corona Cards Enterprise and embed the Corona into XCode projects and use it as a control.